Telegraf and sql output plugin
i would like to configure output sql plugin for telegraf but i don not understand how it work.
Telegraf as a modbus input plugin and it work fine , with below configuration it create a tabke but telegraf cant write on it, it say
[agent] Error writing to outputs.sql: mssql: There is already an object named 'modbus' in the database. 
Telegraf create this table

Configuration File
[agent]
  debug=true
  quiet=false
  interval = "1s"
  round_interval = true
  flush_interval = "1s"
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"

[[inputs.modbus]]
        name = "PM5300_SAS"
        slave_id = 255
        timeout = "2s"
        controller = "tcp://10.0.2.103:502"
        configuration_type  = "register"
        holding_registers=[
                { name = "VAB", byte_order = "ABCD",data_type = "FLOAT32-IEEE",scale=1.0, address= [3019,3020]},
                { name = "VAC", byte_order = "ABCD",data_type = "FLOAT32-IEEE",scale=1.0, address= [3021,3022]},
                { name = "VBC", byte_order = "ABCD",data_type = "FLOAT32-IEEE",scale=1.0, address= [3023,3024]},
                ]

[[outputs.sql]]

        driver="mssql"
        timestamp_column = "timestamp"
        data_source_name = "sqlserver://sa:xxxxxxx@yyyyyyy:1433/?database=test"
        table_exists_template = "SELECT 1 FROM {TABLE} LIMIT 1"

        [outputs.sql.convert]
        integer              = "INT"
        real                 = "FLOAT"
        text                 = "TEXT"
        timestamp            = "datetimeoffset(7)"
        defaultvalue         = "TEXT"
        bool                 = "BIT"
        unsigned             = ""

[[outputs.file]]
  files = ["stdout"]

How can i see the query of telegraf? is there somebody tath can help me?
Tank you in adavance!
